# Google map is not working Properly after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have a google map with five regions, works fine on load. But when it comes as ajax using jquery the google map is half or small. please help. Is delegate or live will work for google maps?

Comment: got an example or some code that produces this problem? imposible to say what the problem could be at this point

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already solved this problem, but just in case someone else has a similar issue, here is the likely culprit . . .

You are suffering from the way that google maps determines which tiles of the map to show in the map canvas.  Google determines the size of the map canvas (and thus, which tiles to show) only on the map load.  If you load a map into a small space, only to show a larger map later (this often happens, for example, when you load a map into a jquery ui tab that is not yet being displayed, and then click on the tab to display the map), then google maps will only show a single title off to the left top space of the map canvas.

The good news is that there is an easy fix.  All you need to do is call checkResize() on your google maps instance.

Hope this helps.